# Problem with Dynamic Data and entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

I'm trying to use Dynamic Data with a entity model that has Abstract class that are Derived by sub entities.

Whenever i run the website i get this error:

model.RegisterContext(typeof(QMSModel.QMSEntities), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = false });[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() +28   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +7452124   System.Web.DynamicData.ModelProviders.EFAssociationProvider..ctor(EFColumnProvider column, NavigationProperty navigationProperty) +336   System.Web.DynamicData.ModelProviders.EFColumnProvider.get_Association() +82   System.Web.DynamicData.MetaColumn.Create(MetaTable table, ColumnProvider columnProvider) +16   System.Web.DynamicData.MetaTable..ctor(MetaModel metaModel, TableProvider tableProvider, Boolean scaffoldAllTables, String nameOverride) +272   System.Web.DynamicData.MetaModel.RegisterContext(DataModelProvider dataModelProvider, ContextConfiguration configuration) +758   System.Web.DynamicData.MetaModel.RegisterContext(Func`1 contextFactory, ContextConfiguration configuration) +359   System.Web.DynamicData.MetaModel.RegisterContext(Type contextType, ContextConfiguration configuration) +79   ASP.global_asax.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in c:\Projects\DynamicDataWebsite\AdventureWebSite\Global.asax:19   ASP.global_asax.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\DynamicDataWebsite\AdventureWebSite\Global.asax:49

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that [Dynamic Data is broken when your Entity Framework model contains inheritance of any kind](http://66.129.67.4/p/1277132/2431739.aspx). This is supposed to be [fixed in DD 4.0 Preview 3](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Dynamic%20Data&referringTitle=Home), but I have not tested that.

My overall impression is that the Dynamic Data support for the Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC is still, to put it charitably, a work in progress.